# FileHelpers: CsvEngine.DataTableToCsv creates invalid CSV

Tags: c#, csv, escaping, export-to-csv, filehelpers

I'm using FileHelpers to export dynamically created data from my application. I have a DataGridView whose columns and rows can be edited by the users (add, delete, manipulated), so I have no idea what data is finally passed to FileHelpers.

Reading [Dynamically create a CSV file with FileHelpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112924/dynamically-create-a-csv-file-with-filehelpers/2112993#2112993) pointed me to the [CsvEngine.DataTableToCsv](http://www.filehelpers.com/FileHelpers.CsvEngine.DataTableToCsv_overloads.html) method. Unfortunatly, this method does neither escape fields containing the delimiter nor doublequotes nor newlines.

If I had a predefined class, I could use the FieldQuoted-Annotation to make FileHelper use a proper format, but since that is not the case, I do not know how to archive this with dynamically created data.

**//Edit: Some code / Current approach:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the Data in a DGV into a DataTable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataGridView"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DataTable GetDataTableFromDGV(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        DataTable myDT = new DataTable();
        // add Columns
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
        {
            myDT.Columns.Add(col.Name);
        };

        // add Rows
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            List<Object> line = new List<object>();
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                line.Add(cell.Value);
            }
            myDT.Rows.Add(line.ToArray<Object>());
        }
        return myDT;
    }

    public void main(){

        String filename = "test.csv"
        DataTable dt = GetDataTableFromDGV(this.dgv);
        CsvEngine.DataTableToCsv(dt, filename, ',');

    }
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

FileHelpers is not so powerful when you can't use a predefined class.

However, since you are visiting every value when you convert from your `DataGridView`, why not handle your escaping there?

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
{
    line.Add(AddDoubleQuotesAndEscapeIfNecessary(cell.Value));
}
```